# Can't add LeftBarButton using storyboard in ios8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uibarbuttonitem

I am creating project in which I have to use leftBarButton and rightBarButton. I am using storyboard and I dragged barButton it set right hand side(Done button) but When I want to drag another bar button on left hand side(Cancel button) of the navigation bar I am not able to drag it.

[image]

[image]

So, anyone can tell me how can I add barbutton left hand side?

Comment: is your layout set up to add the backbarbutton on the left side?

Comment: @Steve which kind of setup are you talking about?

Comment: nevermind I believe if you add a left bar button it overrides the default back button of the navigation controller. I just opened a project of mine that has a back button and it let me add the left button no problem

Answer (score 1):

**its very easy to add just see that and follow navigation bar item flow.**
[image: ans]

Comment: you need one more bar button item left side so now you pick one bar button item then put on left side on navigation bar.

Comment: pike one bar button item then drag and drop on navigation left bar.

Comment: I am not able to drag another button to left hand side of navigation bar.

Comment: I think you not added bar button item in navigation bar. pls check this.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you were trying to drag the UIBarButton under the navigation Item in left side like the screen shoot below-
[image]

Don't dop that way. For some reason, it doesn't work. Rather than that try to drag it on the right hand side on your View Controller in Storyboard.

[image]

The see image above. May be that help.

Comment: What i do is I drag Bar Button Item from Library to left hand side of view controller.